# Clojure - Assertions regarding sequences, using "identical?"

Tags: clojure, assert, equality

In my program I am trying to test my program by writing tests that verify the functionality of my defined functions. I am testing the equality of sequences after they have passed through my function.

Definition of my-reverse:

```
(defn my-reverse [coll]
  (if (empty? coll)
    []
    (conj
      (my-reverse (rest coll))
      (first coll)
    )
  )
)
```

I do not know why I am failing the assertion, as (my-reverse [1]) returns [1].
Here is the assertion:

```
(assert (identical? (my-reverse [1]) [1]))
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Can you please post the definition of `my-reverse`?

Comment: Just generally, `identical?` is almost never the right answer. Clojure leans heavily on value-based equality so `=` is almost always the right way to compare data structures in Clojure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`identical?` only returns `true` if the arguments refer to the same object, which will not be the case if your `my-reverse` function constructs a new list. You can just use `=`:

```
(assert (= (my-reverse [1]) [1]))
```